# Measure scanner input length

Tags: java, input, char

I want a scanner that will ask the user to input a character, however if more than one character is entered it should prompt the user again for only one character.

This is what I have so far:

```
System.out.print("(Player 2) Guess a letter: ");
Scanner letterScan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(letterScan.nextLine().length()>1)
{
    System.out.print("(Player 2) Please guess only one letter: ");

    //char inputLetter = letterScan.next().charAt(0);
}
char inputLetter = letterScan.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("letter: " + inputLetter);
```

The only problem is, this is the output when I run it:

```
(Player 2) Guess a letter: asfa
(Player 2) Please guess only one letter: a
s
letter: s
```

You see the third line? It's asking for another prompt. I want to get rid of that and make it so that it uses the letter in the 2nd line from the output instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `letterScan.next()` is reading an additional character after you get your correct line. You need to save the first input of 1 character you receive, like so:

```
System.out.print("(Player 2) Guess a letter: ");
Scanner letterScan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = "";
//just check for one character.
while((line=letterScan.nextLine()).length()!=1)
{
    System.out.print("(Player 2) Please guess only one letter: ");
}
char inputLetter = line.charAt(0);
System.out.println("letter: " + inputLetter);
```

Also change your while loop to just check the input has 1 character, otherwise the player could just press enter and your code would crash as the input would have 0 characters. The code above does this too.

Comment: That doesn't work. You're comparing a string to a number in the while loop condition.

Comment: Not sure what you guys are saying here... the code I've posted works fine. I did have a small edit. Perhaps it wasn't refreshed on your screens yet?

Comment: I'm not sure why you changed the ">" to a "==" since that changes the condition that I needed, but otherwise the code works. I changed the == back to a >1 like I had it before. The trick was having the empty String in the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: @user2124252 I was mistaken, it needs to be `!=`, not `==`. `>1` will allow the loop to exit if a string of 0 length is input, meaning the next line where you reference character 0 will cause a crash. Try it with `>1`, just press return with no input. It will crash for that case if you don't use `!=1`

Comment: I see that you changed it to a !=. Thanks for that. Made me rethink it and it makes more sense since I did not account for an empty entry

Comment: @user2124252 its difficult to consider all possible input. Thanks for the accept, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

its because this line:

```
char inputLetter = letterScan.next().charAt(0);
```

remove the above line & change this statement:

```
while(letterScan.nextLine().length()>1)
```

to

```
String line = letterScan.nextLine();
while(line.length()>1)
```

Comment: +1, though the while loop is also flawed. I address this in my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the following output instead:
(Player 2) Guess a letter: adad
adsad
ada
ada
(Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2) Please guess only one letter: (Player 2)

Comment: @user2124252 you try mine?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code... Comments in the code explain the answer.

```
    System.out.print("(Player 2) Guess a letter: "); //prompt
    Scanner letterScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = ""; //create string for input
    while((input = letterScan.nextLine()).length() != 1) { //while they entered more than one letter
        System.out.print("(Player 2) Please guess only one letter: "); //re-prompt
    }
    char inputLetter = input.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("letter: " + inputLetter); //print the letter
```

Previously you were getting `.next()` again to get new input, but here we save your input and then get the first character.

Comment: While loop is also flawed.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Mine is?

Comment: No the OP's is, not yours. It will crash with no input. I've addressed this in my answer, just heads up.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Ah... Got it.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Actually, your while loop was flawed... ;) I edited it.